# Handling newlines in data with Json.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, newline, json.net

Is there any way to handle newlines in JSON.NET.  I have some data coming back with Carriage Return Line Feed in it and Json.Net is just leaving it raw in the return value.  Is there a way to force Json.Net to encode this for Json.  I assumed this would happen by default but it is not happening for me. Maybe I am missing something else.

I am using Json.Net in a MVC4 WebApi project if that matters.

My data is coming back with \r\n in the string such as

```
  "Keywords": "These are my keywords.\r\n\r\n\r\nThis is a second line...\r\n\r\nThis is a third line. ...\r\n\r\n\r\nThis is a 4th line ..."
```

From what I understand, that should be 
`\\r\\n`.  It could be a problem with the data I am returning, but I just wanted to see what JSON.NET should be doing with this.

Comment: how is your input and what output do you expect?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by 'encode this for json'?  It's completely kosher by the JSON spec for data to come back with CRLF in it.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that even if the serialized Json object looked correct in the debugger, when I write it to file it gets all these literals added (i.e. backslashes are added).

What worked was to parse the obtained json as a `Token`, and then use the token instead.

For example:

```cs
// Serialize and convert to Token
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject);
var token = JToken.Parse(json);

// Save to file
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.Serialize(filepath, token);
```

I honestly do not understand why this would be needed, or if there is a better way around this. Feedback in comment is appreciated.

Answer (score -5):

You can serialize your object with the option Formatting.Indented. 
Like this:

```
string yourJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject,  Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { });
```

I think this should work.

Regards.